A Weird Integral Problem

Let the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ have the derivative $f^{\prime}(x)$ continuous and positive in $[1,3]$ satisfying:

$2 f^{\prime}(1)=$ $3 f^{\prime}(3)=4 f(1)=8$
$\displaystyle \int_1^3 f^{\prime \prime}(x) \sqrt{\frac{x^3}{f^{\prime}(x)}} d x=4-4 \sqrt{2} \int_1^3 \sqrt{x+1+\frac{x^2\left(f^{\prime}(x)\right)^2}{4(x+1)}} d x=\frac{16 \sqrt{2}-8}{3}$

Evaluate $\displaystyle\int_1^3 f(x) d x$.

The following shows my attempt:


Where is this problem from? is it a homework of a class or a test question ?

Which substitution(s) did you try? How does the Laplace transform relate here? What exactly does "dividing the integral into different interval" entail?
